# ROR Console + Specific column should show distinct values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-console

At Rails Console, I am trying to collect a distinct values of column.

For example : User model have  a column name having status, in that column we store the status of that specific user.

```
Status are like ('NEW','PREMIUM','TEMP','BLOCKED','ON_HOLD' and etc)
```

At rails console, I am trying to get all this value in output. I am not getting the way to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.uniq.pluck(:status)
# => ['NEW','PREMIUM','TEMP', ...]
```

Comment: Getting Error : NoMethodError: undefined method `distinct' for #<Class:0x00000008aaab10>

Comment: @Rubyist I've updated my answer, the right method for Rails 3.2 is `uniq` (`distinct` is only for Rails 4)